# C# SetWinEventHook stops sending messages on mouse move

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, events, hook

In my C# WPF application.

I am setting a hook in the window Initialized callback:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess,  uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

IntPtr hookHandle = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_MIN, EVENT_MAX, IntPtr.Zero, TestCallback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD);
```

and I am logging the message in the callback

```
private void TestCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    SetStatus("The eventType is: " + eventType);
}
```

However, whenever I mouse over the space in my WPF window.

The events stop sending completely.

On a possibly unrelated note, I was getting a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Unhandled exception in one of the system dlls sometimes.

Why does mousing over cause the win hook to fail?

My ultimate goal is to get an event whenever a new window is created/shown on the desktop so that I don't have to poll it in a loop that takes a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your issue here is that the garbage collector (GC) eventually collects the `TestCallback` delegate that you pass to the unmanaged `SetWinEventHook` function.

Since the GC cannot track references held by native code, you should store a reference to the callback in a `WinEventDelegate` field yourself, e.g.:

```
private IntPtr hookHandle;
private readonly WinEventDelegate callback;

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    callback = new WinEventDelegate(TestCallback);
}

protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    hookHandle = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_MIN, EVENT_MAX, IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD);
}

//...
```

Note that you should also keep track of the `IntPtr` returned by the `SetWinEventHook` function to be able to pass it to the `UnhookWinEvent` method whenever you want to remove the hook, for example when the window is closed.